# How to count occurences of a word following by a special character in a text using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, counter

I want to count the number of occurrences of the word 'people' in a text using python. For that I use Counter and Python's regular expression:

```
    for j in range(len(paragraphs)):
        text = paragraphs[j].text
        count[j] = Counter(re.findall(r'\bpeople\b' ,text))
```

Yet, here my code does not take into account of the occurrences of people. people! people? 
How can I modify it to also count the cases when the word is followed by a specific character?

Thank you for you help,

Comment: Your regex looks correct (and works for my tests). I think your error is `Counter()`. What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an optional character-group in your regex:

```
r'\bpeople[.,!?]?\b'
```

The ? specifies it can occure 0 or 1 times - the `[]` specifies what characters are allowed. There is no need to escape the `.` (or f.e. `()*+?`) inside `[]` although they have special meaning for regex. If you wanted to use a `-` inside `[]` you would need to escape it as it is used to denote ranges in sets `[1-5]` == `12345`.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

> **[]** Used to indicate a set of characters. In a set:
>
> Characters can be listed individually, e.g. [amk] will match 'a', 'm', or 'k'.
> Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-', for example [a-z] will match any lowercase ASCII letter, [0-5][0-9] will match all the two-digits numbers from 00 to 59, and [0-9A-Fa-f] will match any hexadecimal digit.  [...]

Answer (score 1):

```
people[?.!]
```

This will allow you to only match with people? people. and/or people!

So if you add a few more `Counter(re.finall(` you will be able to do something like this

```
#This will only match people
count[j] = Counter(re.findall(r'people\s' ,text))

#This will only match people?
count[j] = Counter(re.findall(r'people\?' ,text))

#This will only match people.
count[j] = Counter(re.findall(r'people\.' ,text))

#This will only match people!
count[j] = Counter(re.findall(r'people\!' ,text))
```

You need to use the `\` to escape the special characters

Also this is a good resource when you are experimenting with python regular expressions: https://pythex.org/ The site also has a regular expression cheat sheet

Comment: no need to put `|` in the [] unless you want to allow it as character as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modifier statement at the end of the 'people' part of your Regex pattern. Try the following:

```
for j in range(len(paragraphs)):
    text = paragraphs[j].text
    count[j] = Counter(re.findall('r\bpeople[.?!]?\b', text)
```

The ? is for zero or more quantifier. The above pattern seems to work on regex101.com but I haven't tried in out in a Python shell yet.

Comment: I went a head and edited my response to remove the extra backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to use regex? Why not just:

```
len(text.split("people"))-1
```